# What's the name of this theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry

If $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ issmooth function and $g^{(i)}(t)=0$ for $1\le i \le k-1$ and $g^{(k)}(t) \neq 0$ then there exists a smooth map $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ such that

$g(x) = (x-t)^kf(x)$

> Does anybody know if this theorem has a name and where I can find a
>   proof of it?

Comment: That's certainly false if $g$ is not smooth.

Comment: @Chappers Thanks for the comment. I corrected my question.

Comment: Okay, your next problem is that you haven't defined multiplication on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^n$, and $(x-t)^k$ lives in the first, $f(x)$ in the second.

Comment: This seems like Taylor's theorem in disguise (once you get the statement worked out properly). You might as well take $t$ to be the origin (because otherwise you can translate). Once you do that, you can just *define* $f(x) = g(x) / x^k$; you need only prove that this definition can be extended to $x = 0$, which amounts to showing that a certain limit exists...which it does because of all the derivative assumptions.

Comment: @Chappers I believe what I was looking for is called Hadamard's lemma.

Comment: @JohnHughes I believe what I was looking for is called Hadamard's lemma.